# Difficulty watching streaming video

Tags: streaming, lag

I have Verizon FIOS and until a few days ago had no problems at all with its performance. Recently, I've noticed sporadic difficulty streaming on sites like youtube.com and twitch.tv and was hoping to diagnose why this could possibly be.

Here are results of a current Speedtest, which I think are well beyond the range where I'd need to have trouble watching 720p and even some 480p videos.

[image: 14.75 down, 16.70 up]

If there's any other information I can give feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out!

Apparently TWC is throttling some sites, but adding a few simple inbound rules in my Windows Firewall fixed the issue.

To get around this, you can block the following IP ranges (Windows Firewall, ipfw in Linux):

173.194.55.0/24
206.111.0.0/16

By blocking these addresses, the videos will be served to you directly instead of being throttled by the ISP. You can read more info about it [here](http://mitchribar.com/2013/02/time-warner-cable-sucks-for-youtube-twitchtv/). It should have some more detailed information and links to some videos and tutorials for Windows, OSX, and Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Is there anyone else using your connection that could be sucking up the bandwidth?

Also what time is it where you are? A lot of speed test sites such as the one you used only run their speedtests over the http protocol (port 80) which doesn't always give you a 100% accurate representation of your real speeds. Many providers (including my uk provider Virgin Media) traffic manage heavy bandwidth sites such as youtube/netflix etc during peak times.